# Why did my question about security get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, downvotes

While learning web security, there was something that seemed to me like popular websites like Facebook and PayPal have a security issue (as they allow user enumeration) or I understood things wrong. I asked why they allow it if it is a security issue, but my question got downvoted two times.

What mistake did I make while writing the question? This is the link, but I may delete the question if it gets downvoted again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73869527/why-do-important-sites-allow-user-enumeration?noredirect=1

I am still kind of a beginner on Stack Overflow, so please tell me if I wrote anything not allowed.

Comment: Should probably be on https://security.stackexchange.com/ (though I have no idea if it is on topic there either) it isn't really about programming and won't be well received on Stack Overflow as you've found out.

Comment: The question does not seem to match any of the on-topic items of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Security questions are imho only on-topic on SO when they are directly related to a specific piece of code. General security question are off-topic.

Comment: Aside from the off-topic issue, a question phrased "why does X allow Y?" will often be received poorly. The answer can be pure speculation or opinion and would only be "truely" valid if provided from X or documentation where X states their reasoning.

Answer (score 16):

It's not a fit on Stack Overflow, and while I'd be *reluctant* to suggest this, Security.SE has [a whole tag dedicated to user enumeration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-enumeration).  It would be worth first perusing [what is on topic on their site ***first***](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), then reading through that list of questions ***second*** to see if yours is answered, and then asking your question ***last*** if you can't find enough information to pull together an answer for your question.